# How to allow only certain Clients-Users combinations in Spring Security Oauth2?

Tags: java, spring-security, oauth-2.0, jwt, spring-security-oauth2

In my application I have a ClientUser join table which defines which Users can login using what Clients. Based on that I want to be able to not issue a token in case the pair is invalid.

The way I would like it to work is for ClientDetails to have a method which would define which Users can authenticate using given Client, but obviously ClientDetails has no such method.

In this case the only idea I have is to add a filter to Spring Security which would refuse access after recognizing invalid User-Client combo, however it seems silly to grant a token in the first place.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by Clients.  Is that iOS, Android, Chrome, Firefox?  Or are you referring to something else?  Thanks.

Comment: By Client I mean a third-party application that is attempting to get access to the User's account.

Comment: You could implement a custom `ClientDetailsService`.